# How to get the Standard deviation of this array

Tags: java, arrays, std

Ok so i have a code set out to get the mean of an array that has upto 50 elements, i want to also find the standard deviation of those elements and show it right under where it would display the mean, my code so far is

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class caArray
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("How many numbers you want to calculate average upto 50 : ");

    int n = input.nextInt();
    int[] array = new int[50];
    int sum = 0;


    for (int m = 0; m < n; m++)
    {
        System.out.print("Number " + m + " : ");
        array[m] = input.nextInt();
    }


    for (int m = 0; m < n; m++)
    {
        sum = array[m] + sum;
    }


    {
        System.out.println("Total value of Numbers = " + sum);
    }


    {
        double avg;
        avg = sum / array.length;
        System.out.println("Average of Numbers = " + avg);  //calculate average value
    }
}
}
```

i need to add into this to get the standard deviation in the one program

EDIT** I cannot use the functions as i actully have to use the standard deviation fourmula withing the program itself

Comment: Good you want Standard Deviation of array. But have you given a try to convert SD formula into java code?

Comment: [SD formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation) is pretty easy to implement, if you aren't asked for performance, just use it straight.

Comment: you also need a probability for each number to calculate anything

Comment: I cannot use the functions as i actully have to use the standard deviation fourmula withing the program itself

Comment: well just do that :) compute the sqrt of the mean of the square distance of your elements from their mean.

Comment: If you're not allowed to use functions, then this sounds like a homework assignment...

Comment: Do you mean like this does? http://stackoverflow.com/a/13841799/57695  I would get your code working for the average first.

Answer (score 1):

you can write it in 3 Methods

```
private double standardDeviation(double[] input) {
    return Math.sqrt(variance(input));
}

private double variance(double[] input) {
    double expectedVal = expectedValue(input);
    double variance = 0;
    for(int i = 0;i<input.length;++i) {
        double buffer = input[i] - expectedVal;
        variance += buffer * buffer;
    }
    return variance;
}

private double expectedValue(double[] input) {
    double sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0;i<input.length;++i) {
        sum += input[i];
    }
    return sum/input.length;
}
```

hope it works, i am not quite shure about it, if i used the formulas the right way.

But basicly you have this 3 mathematical formulas in your calculation

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have to write it yourself, check out [Apache Commons Math](http://commons.apache.org/math/). The [stats documentation](http://commons.apache.org/math/userguide/stat.html) references how to derive [standard deviations](http://commons.apache.org/math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/stat/descriptive/DescriptiveStatistics.html#getStandardDeviation%28%29).

As you have to write it yourself, perhaps checking out [the source code](http://kickjava.com/src/org/apache/commons/math/stat/descriptive/DescriptiveStatistics.java.htm) for DescriptiveStatistics would be instructive (look for the function `getStandardDeviation()`)

Comment: I do have to write it myself saddly

Comment: I cannot use the functions as i actully have to use the standard deviation fourmula withing the program itself